# Could you pass these texstudio codes to overleaf codes?

Tags: tables, overleaf

```
\begin{table}[htbp] \centering
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  \centering
  \caption{GAAA}
\label{tab:Creditos}
{\small
\resizebox{18cm}{!}{
\begin{tabularx}{26cm}{lCCCCC}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{MCO}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{MCO}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{EF}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{EF}\\
\hline
noticiasdecrimen\_w  &       0.042***&       0.042*  &       0.002*  &       0.042*  \\
                    &     (0.005)   &     (0.023)   &     (0.001)   &     (0.024)   \\
\hline
N. Obs.             &        1767   &        1767   &        1767   &        1767   \\
R cuadrado          &       0.706   &       0.706   &       0.676   &       0.741   \\
N\_clust             &               &          25   &          25   &          25   \\

\hline\hline
 \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Note: Niveles de signficancia (* 10\%; ** 5\%; *** 1\%). Errores estándar en paréntesis. Var. control: Inversión regional, gasto regional, igv, tasa de referencia, tasa de encaje. La variable dependiente es Crédito Hipotecario. } \\
\end{tabular}
}
```

Comment: The LaTeX code is independent of the editor used.  But this is an **incomplete** document and moreover is **dependent** of some  packages. Without include this as part of  a complete document that  load these packages in the preamble it cannot work (neither in Overleaf nor in any other online/offline editor).

Comment: LaTeX code is just text. So copy ... then paste.

Comment: Start [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner).

Comment: Apart from the code being not a complete document, `\resizebox{18cm}{!}{
\begin{tabularx}{26cm}{` does not really make too much sense. Do not use `resizebox` to change the size of a table. This will only lead t inconsistent font sizes. Instead, you can change the width of the table using the first argument of `tabularx`.